# How do I make sure my part matches with the eagle part selected?

Tags: components, eaglecad, layout, component-selection, footprint

I need help matching the part I have with the eagle part.

I'm using a RPX-1.0 data sheet pdf:
https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/468/RPX_1_0-1903909.pdf

It is a 3mm by 5mm qfn with 16 pins but it doesn't seem to match up with the qfn options on eagle.

When I try searching for *recom*, in eagle, I find the following dc-dc converter
[image]

but it doesn't seem to match with the footprint on the data sheet
[image]

any advice on verifying if the parts match?

Or any advice on how to find the correct part?

Comment: Open the footprint in the library editor. Then compare against the datasheet

Comment: Right - If it doesn't match, it doesn't match.  There's no trick to it.  You're not guaranteed anything really from canned libraries.  If you can't find what you need, you have to make a new schematic part.  Or pick a part that your libraries already support.  I can't think of a single PCB I've ever done (and I've done alot) where I didn't  have to make a couple new schematic symbols and footprints.

Answer (score 0):

Get the datasheet for the part, then check, there are two things that need to be checked:

1. Pinout

At the end of the day the pins on the part need to match the pins on the PCB (otherwise bad things might happen, like connecting GND to VCC and smoke results), especially for SMT parts. In CAN programs the pins are numbered, and almost everyone follows the same pin numbering in the datasheet.

The *order in the schematic* doesn't need to match, but the *function needs to match*.

Check the function against the reference diagram:

[image]
Source: https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/468/RPX_1_0-1903909.pdf

You are correct that they are not the same, The part in your post has a Vref out- and out+ pins, the RPX-1.0 does not.

You may have to create your own part.

2. The other thing that has to match is the foot print, check the dimensions of the part in the datasheet with that of the PCB footprint, they should also match. Sometimes you have to get creative because they only dimension some of the mechanical features, and it's necessary to add and subtract dimensions to come up with the measurements that you need.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is having this same problem I figured out a super easy and obvious solution.

Using the above RPX-1.0 as an example.

I found the part in mouser then under models I selected "RPX-1.0-R Symbol & Footprint by SnapEDA"

Which I can then download the footprint and schematic onto eagle, or a variety of other software.

You do have to make an account and I believe it requires an .edu email